# Session variable doesn't work on my live server

Tags: php, session

I was build a admin panel on localhost, and all functions are working perfectly.
When i uploaded on my live server and i run it, Not working any $_SESSION variables in my code; What can i do.

```
session_start();
include './functions.php';

// Admin login

if (isset($_POST['admin'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $username_password = $username . '-' . $password;
    check_admin($username_password);
    if (in_array($username_password, $dat_admin)) {
        $_SESSION['admin'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $username;
        $valid = 1;
        header('location:../dashboard.php');
    } else {
        $valid = 0;
        header('location:../login_page.php');
    }
}
```